# What is exactly a subsystem of linear equations?

Tags: linear-algebra

I was recently kinda confused on the idea of subsystem

thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a system of linear equations:

$$a_{1,1}x_1+a_{1,2}x_2+....+a_{1,n}x_n=y_1$$

$$a_{2,1}x_1+a_{2,2}x_2+....+a_{2,n}x_n=y_2$$

.......

$$a_{m,1}x_1+a_{m,2}x_2+....+a_{m,n}x_n=y_m$$

This linear system of equations is made up of $m$ different equations. A subsystem of this system would be some subset of these $m$ equations.

If the subsystem has no solution, then full system of linear equations can not have a solution either.

Comment: Sorry I am confused on the word "subset" what does that mean over here, Sorry if I am asking silly question, first year freshmen ;-;

Comment: So consider the set that contains the $m$ different linear equations. A subset of this set would be a set that contains some (possibly all) of these $m$ different linear equations